# Is there a name for a byte/word that doesn't wrap around?

Tags: math, cpu-registers

Certain Processors have registers that are able to do arithmetic on words/bytes without the value wrapping around (i.e. in the case of a byte, the byte is clamped between 0 and 255). I'm not certain but I believe this is used in certain vector extensions designed for image processing (where a clamped byte would be beneficial in terms of representing RGB/RGBA values);

Is there a proper name for arithmetic/registers in which values are clamped and do not wrap or is it/are they just referred to generically as 'non-wrapping arithmetic'/'non-wrapping registers'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [*saturation arithmetic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic). It describes any arithmetic operation that is clamped to a range rather than overflowing.

It is quite common for many forms of signal processing, including image, audio, and video operations.